# .top missing from jquery TypeScript definition files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am using the following code:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top });
```

Typescript is giving me an error message saying:

```
The property 'top' does not exist on value of type 'Object'
```

I am guessing something is missing from the jQuery definition file. Has anyone else seen this problem or is this something that's not normally used with jQuery? It's something I have not seen before.

For more information. Here is the code where this is used:

```
   $.fn.buildTableOfContent = function () {
        "use strict";
        var h2 = this.find('h2');
        if (h2.length > 0) {
            var h1 = this.find('h1:first');
            if (h1.length === 0) {
                h1 = this.prepend('<h1>Help</h1>').children(':first');
            }
            var menu = h1.wrap('<div class="h1 with-menu"></div>')
                    .after('<div class="menu"><img src="/Content/images/menu-open-arrow.png" width="16" height="16"><ul></ul></div>')
                    .next().children('ul');
            h2.each(function (i) {
                this.id = 'step' + i;
                menu.append('<li class="icon_down"><a href="#step' + i + '">' + $(this).html() + '</a></li>');
            });
            menu.find('a').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top });
            });
        }
        return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

From the jquery.d.ts file (line 374 in my version):

```
interface JQuery {
   ...
   offset(): Object;
   offset(coordinates: any): JQuery;
   offset(func: (index: any, coords: any) => any): JQuery;
   ...
}
```

By invoking the function with no parameters the type definition expects the function to return an `Object` type. I looked at the documentation for jQuery and you are correct, the returned object is expected to have `top` and `left` properties on it.

Unfortunately, since there's no such thing as overloading based on return type, you wont be able to add on another member onto the `JQuery` interface. Since, in this particular case, the type definition is simply not as specific as it should be I would recommend simply modifying your jquery.d.ts file and changing the return type so it looks as follows (perhaps string instead of number?):

```
offset(): { top : number; left : number; };
```

If you would rather not modify this file, you also have the option of casting the result to `any` before accessing any properties on it, example:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: (<any> $($(this).attr('href')).offset()).top });
```

The downside is the cast will be necessary each time you invoke that function with no parameters.

Comment: Couldn't you do `offset() ?: { top : number; left : number; };` using the `?:` optional in the TS definition?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I thought that it actually worked, but I was still using the my edited jquery.d.ts which had the modified declaration. Anyway, no, making the `offset` member optional only means that it doesn't have to be implemented in order to have a valid implementation of the `JQuery` interface. It does not appear that you can use it to hide members; if you try to add it to the jquery.d.ts file you'll prevent the other overloads of `offset` from being valid. Also, you'd need to declare it as `offset? : () => { top: number; left: number; };` to even have it be valid syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top });
```

try this

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top });
```